# current subfolder variable for tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

How can i use the current folder name in tasks.json using VSCODE ?
related to the following [variables-reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

example of file path: /home/your-username/your-project/folder/**subfolder**/file.ext
i want to get only the subfolder name.

there is a predefined variable called ${activeFolderShort} in the [following documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) for window title settings. but it's not working in tasks.json file.

here is my task code:

```
{
        "label": "reload",
        "windows": {
            "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
        },
        "args": [
            "http://localhost:52945/${activeFolderShort}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

Comment: I think you are over complicating it. Why don't you just take the text between the last 2 "/" instead of trying to find a way to get a short version of the file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)

Use the variable

```
${command:extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirBasename}
```